# Add cipher suite TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384 to Java 7

Tags: java, java-7, tls1.2, aes-gcm

I'd like to use `TLSv1.2` with `TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384` in Java 7.

I've added `-Ddeployment.security.TLSv1.2=true` to the VM arguments and I'd like to know how to add the cipher suite mentioned above.

Comment: Java 7 JSSE (the SSL/TLS provider) does not implement GCM ciphersuites, only Java 8 does. A thirdparty provider like BouncyCastle might. Also remember all Oracle/Sun JREs support AES-256 suites (and more-than-128-bit symmetric encryption generally) only if the JCE Unlimited Strength option is installed.

Comment: @dave_thompson_085:  I didn't mention it in the post but I've previously tried the JCE Unlimited Strength Jurisdiction Policy Files as well as the bouncy castle provider. A few additional cipher suites became available but not this one in particular.

Comment: I said (Java8 OR MAYBE BC) AND (UnlimitedStrength OR NOT Oracle -- or more exactly openjdk). I thought I recalled BCprov doing SSL/TLS but on checking it's only the lightweight API, so unless you rewrite your code (and any involved libraries) you need (Java8 to get GCM) AND (UnlimitedStrength OR openjdk to get AES256).

Comment: I'm already using OpenJDK 8 and have access to this specific cipher suite. Thank you for the explanation. (If OpenJDK does not need the unlimited strength policy files, I take it it is not affected by export restrictions like Oracle's JDK?)

Comment: I don't try to understand the export regulations. Wild guesses: it *may* make a difference that openjdk started much more recently than Sun, or is fully opensource, or from a distributed group of people and not a business. There may even be magic with the mirrors or rpms I don't see because I'm USAnian. All I know for sure is the installed policy jars are different.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hints provided by [@ dave_thompson_085](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2868801/dave-thompson-085).

> Java 7 JSSE (the SSL/TLS provider) does not implement GCM ciphersuites, only Java 8 does. A thirdparty provider like BouncyCastle might. Also remember all Oracle/Sun JREs support AES-256 suites (and more-than-128-bit symmetric encryption generally) only if the JCE Unlimited Strength option is installed.

---

> I said (Java8 OR MAYBE BC) AND (UnlimitedStrength OR NOT Oracle -- or more exactly openjdk). I thought I recalled BCprov doing SSL/TLS but on checking it's only the lightweight API, so unless you rewrite your code (and any involved libraries) you need (Java8 to get GCM) AND (UnlimitedStrength OR openjdk to get AES256).