# Not able to send push notification to iOS devices through MFP Server V8 Console

Tags: apple-push-notifications, ibm-mobilefirst, mobilefirst-server

I am trying to send a push notification to an iOS device through MobileFirstPlatform V8.0 Server Console but when I am sending the notification I am getting the following error:

```
An error occurred while the notification was sent. Internal server error. No devices found.
```

I checked in `Home -> mfp -> Devices`, the devices exist there:

[image]

I am able to successfullly send a notification to the android devices. Its just the iOS ones which are causing the problem.

**UPDATE**

I enabled the trace and when I am sending the notifications, i am getting below Exception:

```
[3/1/17 10:16:29:211 CST] 00005aa0 ApnsConnectio E com.ibm.mfp.push.server.notification.apns.ApnsConnectionImpl sendMessage Couldn't send message after 3 retries.Message(Id=3; Token=40FBDFAF756CE361D66D0DF65CEB54A6E7130477D7A564E83E2AB9C7F9244749; Payload={"aps":{"alert":{"body":"test","action-loc-key":null}},"payload":"{\"nid\":\"bcf2c3a\",\"tag\":\"Push.ALL\"}"})
                                 javax.net.ssl.SSLException: Received fatal alert: internal_error
    at sun.security.ssl.Alerts.getSSLException(Alerts.java:208)
    at sun.security.ssl.Alerts.getSSLException(Alerts.java:154)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.recvAlert(SSLSocketImpl.java:1959)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readRecord(SSLSocketImpl.java:1077)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.performInitialHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1312)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.writeRecord(SSLSocketImpl.java:702)
    at sun.security.ssl.AppOutputStream.write(AppOutputStream.java:122)
    at java.io.OutputStream.write(OutputStream.java:75)
    at com.ibm.mfp.push.server.notification.apns.ApnsConnectionImpl.sendMessage(ApnsConnectionImpl.java:302)
    at com.ibm.mfp.push.server.notification.apns.ApnsConnectionImpl.sendMessage(ApnsConnectionImpl.java:292)
    at com.notnoop.apns.internal.ApnsPooledConnection$2.run(ApnsPooledConnection.java:47)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

[3/1/17 10:16:29:214 CST] 00005aa0 DeploymentReg 1 com.ibm.mfp.server.core.internal.deployment.registry.DeploymentRegistryImpl getAll:255 DeploymentRegistryImpl: getting all- type: com.ibm.mfp.server.core.internal.configuration.analytics.AnalyticsDynamicConfigurationImpl returned: []
[3/1/17 10:16:29:214 CST] 00005aa0 DeploymentReg 1 com.ibm.mfp.server.core.internal.deployment.registry.DeploymentRegistryImpl get:198 DeploymentRegistryImpl: get (one)- type: com.ibm.mfp.server.core.internal.configuration.analytics.AnalyticsDynamicConfigurationImpl returned: null
[3/1/17 10:16:29:214 CST] 00005aa0 AnalyticsConf 1 com.ibm.mfp.server.core.internal.configuration.analytics.AnalyticsConfigurationDeploymentHandler getAdditionalPackages:51 Entering method: getAdditionalPackages().
[3/1/17 10:16:29:214 CST] 00005aa0 AnalyticsConf 1 com.ibm.mfp.server.core.internal.configuration.analytics.AnalyticsConfigurationDeploymentHandler getAdditionalPackages:54 Exiting method: getAdditionalPackages() with value 'null'.
[3/1/17 10:16:29:215 CST] 00005aa0 ApplicationCo E com.ibm.mfp.push.server.notification.apns.ApplicationConnection APNSDelegate.messageSendFailed FPWSE1083E: Failure sending Apple Push Notification Service (APNS) notification with identifier 3, device token: 40FBDFAF756CE361D66D0DF65CEB54A6E7130477D7A564E83E2AB9C7F9244749.
                                 javax.net.ssl.SSLException: Received fatal alert: internal_error
    at sun.security.ssl.Alerts.getSSLException(Alerts.java:208)
    at sun.security.ssl.Alerts.getSSLException(Alerts.java:154)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.recvAlert(SSLSocketImpl.java:1959)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readRecord(SSLSocketImpl.java:1077)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.performInitialHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1312)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.writeRecord(SSLSocketImpl.java:702)
    at sun.security.ssl.AppOutputStream.write(AppOutputStream.java:122)
    at java.io.OutputStream.write(OutputStream.java:75)
    at com.ibm.mfp.push.server.notification.apns.ApnsConnectionImpl.sendMessage(ApnsConnectionImpl.java:302)
    at com.ibm.mfp.push.server.notification.apns.ApnsConnectionImpl.sendMessage(ApnsConnectionImpl.java:292)
```

**UPDATE 2**

```
[3/2/17 8:55:02:995 CST] 0000babb ContextProper 1   JNDI Access (/mfpadmin) not found in cache for key mfp.admin.proxy.scheme
[3/2/17 8:55:02:995 CST] 0000babb DeploymentReg 1 com.ibm.mfp.server.core.internal.deployment.registry.DeploymentRegistryImpl getAll:255 DeploymentRegistryImpl: getting all- type: com.ibm.mfp.server.core.internal.configuration.analytics.AnalyticsDynamicConfigurationImpl returned: []
[3/2/17 8:55:02:995 CST] 0000babb DeploymentReg 1 com.ibm.mfp.server.core.internal.deployment.registry.DeploymentRegistryImpl get:198 DeploymentRegistryImpl: get (one)- type: com.ibm.mfp.server.core.internal.configuration.analytics.AnalyticsDynamicConfigurationImpl returned: null
[3/2/17 8:55:02:995 CST] 0000babb AnalyticsConf 1 com.ibm.mfp.server.core.internal.configuration.analytics.AnalyticsConfigurationDeploymentHandler getAdditionalPackages:51 Entering method: getAdditionalPackages().
[3/2/17 8:55:02:995 CST] 00009c5e DeploymentReg 1 com.ibm.mfp.server.core.internal.deployment.registry.DeploymentRegistryImpl getAll:255 DeploymentRegistryImpl: getting all- type: com.ibm.mfp.server.core.internal.configuration.analytics.AnalyticsDynamicConfigurationImpl returned: []
[3/2/17 8:55:02:995 CST] 0000babb AnalyticsConf 1 com.ibm.mfp.server.core.internal.configuration.analytics.AnalyticsConfigurationDeploymentHandler getAdditionalPackages:54 Exiting method: getAdditionalPackages() with value 'null'.
[3/2/17 8:55:02:995 CST] 00009c5e DeploymentReg 1 com.ibm.mfp.server.core.internal.deployment.registry.DeploymentRegistryImpl get:198 DeploymentRegistryImpl: get (one)- type: com.ibm.mfp.server.core.internal.configuration.analytics.AnalyticsDynamicConfigurationImpl returned: null
[3/2/17 8:55:02:996 CST] 00009c5e AnalyticsConf 1 com.ibm.mfp.server.core.internal.configuration.analytics.AnalyticsConfigurationDeploymentHandler getAdditionalPackages:51 Entering method: getAdditionalPackages().
[3/2/17 8:55:02:996 CST] 00009c5e AnalyticsConf 1 com.ibm.mfp.server.core.internal.configuration.analytics.AnalyticsConfigurationDeploymentHandler getAdditionalPackages:54 Exiting method: getAdditionalPackages() with value 'null'.
[3/2/17 8:55:02:996 CST] 00009c5e PushServiceDB 1 com.ibm.mfp.push.server.core.PushServiceDBQuery buildEnvSelector() selectorString is PushEnvironment.getByEnvironment
[3/2/17 8:55:02:996 CST] 0000babb ContextProper 1   JNDI Access via getContextProperty in /mfpadmin to mfp.admin.proxy.scheme => null
[3/2/17 8:55:02:996 CST] 0000a073 JPAStoreManag < com.ibm.worklight.admin.jpa.datastore.JPAStoreManager getGlobalConfigs RETURN [com.ibm.worklight.admin.entity.GlobalConfigEntity[ id=1 ]]
[3/2/17 8:55:02:996 CST] 0000babb DeploymentReg 1 com.ibm.mfp.server.core.internal.deployment.registry.DeploymentRegistryImpl getAll:255 DeploymentRegistryImpl: getting all- type: com.ibm.mfp.server.core.internal.configuration.analytics.AnalyticsDynamicConfigurationImpl returned: []
[3/2/17 8:55:02:996 CST] 0000a073 DeploymentReg 1 com.ibm.mfp.server.core.internal.deployment.registry.DeploymentRegistryImpl getAll:255 DeploymentRegistryImpl: getting all- type: com.ibm.mfp.server.core.internal.configuration.analytics.AnalyticsDynamicConfigurationImpl returned: []
[3/2/17 8:55:02:996 CST] 0000babb DeploymentReg 1 com.ibm.mfp.server.core.internal.deployment.registry.DeploymentRegistryImpl get:198 DeploymentRegistryImpl: get (one)- type: com.ibm.mfp.server.core.internal.configuration.analytics.AnalyticsDynamicConfigurationImpl returned: null
[3/2/17 8:55:02:996 CST] 0000a073 DeploymentReg 1 com.ibm.mfp.server.core.internal.deployment.registry.DeploymentRegistryImpl get:198 DeploymentRegistryImpl: get (one)- type: com.ibm.mfp.server.core.internal.configuration.analytics.AnalyticsDynamicConfigurationImpl returned: null
[3/2/17 8:55:02:996 CST] 0000babb AnalyticsConf 1 com.ibm.mfp.server.core.internal.configuration.analytics.AnalyticsConfigurationDeploymentHandler getAdditionalPackages:51 Entering method: getAdditionalPackages().
[3/2/17 8:55:02:996 CST] 0000a073 AnalyticsConf 1 com.ibm.mfp.server.core.internal.configuration.analytics.AnalyticsConfigurationDeploymentHandler getAdditionalPackages:51 Entering method: getAdditionalPackages().
[3/2/17 8:55:02:997 CST] 0000babb AnalyticsConf 1 com.ibm.mfp.server.core.internal.configuration.analytics.AnalyticsConfigurationDeploymentHandler getAdditionalPackages:54 Exiting method: getAdditionalPackages() with value 'null'.
[3/2/17 8:55:02:997 CST] 0000a073 AnalyticsConf 1 com.ibm.mfp.server.core.internal.configuration.analytics.AnalyticsConfigurationDeploymentHandler getAdditionalPackages:54 Exiting method: getAdditionalPackages() with value 'null'.
[3/2/17 8:55:02:997 CST] 00009c5e DeploymentReg 1 com.ibm.mfp.server.core.internal.deployment.registry.DeploymentRegistryImpl getAll:255 DeploymentRegistryImpl: getting all- type: com.ibm.mfp.server.core.internal.configuration.analytics.AnalyticsDynamicConfigurationImpl returned: []
[3/2/17 8:55:02:998 CST] 00009c5e DeploymentReg 1 com.ibm.mfp.server.core.internal.deployment.registry.DeploymentRegistryImpl get:198 DeploymentRegistryImpl: get (one)- type: com.ibm.mfp.server.core.internal.configuration.analytics.AnalyticsDynamicConfigurationImpl returned: null
[3/2/17 8:55:02:998 CST] 00009c5e AnalyticsConf 1 com.ibm.mfp.server.core.internal.configuration.analytics.AnalyticsConfigurationDeploymentHandler getAdditionalPackages:51 Entering method: getAdditionalPackages().
[3/2/17 8:55:02:998 CST] 00009c5e AnalyticsConf 1 com.ibm.mfp.server.core.internal.configuration.analytics.AnalyticsConfigurationDeploymentHandler getAdditionalPackages:54 Exiting method: getAdditionalPackages() with value 'null'.
[3/2/17 8:55:02:998 CST] 00009c5e PushServiceIm 1 com.ibm.mfp.push.server.core.PushServiceImpl getResult param name platform value is W
[3/2/17 8:55:02:997 CST] 0000babb JNDIUtils     1   JNDI Access found in cache for context mfpadmin and key mfp.admin.push.url => http://localhost:9081/imfpush
[3/2/17 8:55:02:998 CST] 00007fc9 RequestDetail > com.ibm.mfp.push.server.rest.filter.RequestDetailLogger doFilter() ENTRY
[3/2/17 8:55:02:999 CST] 00007fc9 DeploymentReg 1 com.ibm.mfp.server.core.internal.deployment.registry.DeploymentRegistryImpl getAll:255 DeploymentRegistryImpl: getting all- type: com.ibm.mfp.server.core.internal.configuration.analytics.AnalyticsDynamicConfigurationImpl returned: []
[3/2/17 8:55:02:999 CST] 0000babb DeploymentReg 1 com.ibm.mfp.server.core.internal.deployment.registry.DeploymentRegistryImpl getAll:255 DeploymentRegistryImpl: getting all- type: com.ibm.mfp.server.core.internal.configuration.analytics.AnalyticsDynamicConfigurationImpl returned: []
[3/2/17 8:55:02:999 CST] 00007fc9 DeploymentReg 1 com.ibm.mfp.server.core.internal.deployment.registry.DeploymentRegistryImpl get:198 DeploymentRegistryImpl: get (one)- type: com.ibm.mfp.server.core.internal.configuration.analytics.AnalyticsDynamicConfigurationImpl returned: null
[3/2/17 8:55:02:999 CST] 00007fc9 AnalyticsConf 1 com.ibm.mfp.server.core.internal.configuration.analytics.AnalyticsConfigurationDeploymentHandler getAdditionalPackages:51 Entering method: getAdditionalPackages().
[3/2/17 8:55:02:999 CST] 0000babb DeploymentReg 1 com.ibm.mfp.server.core.internal.deployment.registry.DeploymentRegistryImpl get:198 DeploymentRegistryImpl: get (one)- type: com.ibm.mfp.server.core.internal.configuration.analytics.AnalyticsDynamicConfigurationImpl returned: null
[3/2/17 8:55:02:999 CST] 00007fc9 AnalyticsConf 1 com.ibm.mfp.server.core.internal.configuration.analytics.AnalyticsConfigurationDeploymentHandler getAdditionalPackages:54 Exiting method: getAdditionalPackages() with value 'null'.
[3/2/17 8:55:02:999 CST] 00007fc9 RequestDetail 1 com.ibm.mfp.push.server.rest.filter.RequestDetailLogger doFilter()  Thread count : 303   Request :  308
[3/2/17 8:55:02:999 CST] 00007fc9 DeploymentReg 1 com.ibm.mfp.server.core.internal.deployment.registry.DeploymentRegistryImpl getAll:255 DeploymentRegistryImpl: getting all- type: com.ibm.mfp.server.core.internal.configuration.analytics.AnalyticsDynamicConfigurationImpl returned: []
[3/2/17 8:55:02:999 CST] 00007fc9 DeploymentReg 1 com.ibm.mfp.server.core.internal.deployment.registry.DeploymentRegistryImpl get:198 DeploymentRegistryImpl: get (one)- type: com.ibm.mfp.server.core.internal.configuration.analytics.AnalyticsDynamicConfigurationImpl returned: null
[3/2/17 8:55:02:999 CST] 00007fc9 AnalyticsConf 1 com.ibm.mfp.server.core.internal.configuration.analytics.AnalyticsConfigurationDeploymentHandler getAdditionalPackages:51 Entering method: getAdditionalPackages().
[3/2/17 8:55:02:999 CST] 00009c5e DeploymentReg 1 com.ibm.mfp.server.core.internal.deployment.registry.DeploymentRegistryImpl getAll:255 DeploymentRegistryImpl: getting all- type: com.ibm.mfp.server.core.internal.configuration.analytics.AnalyticsDynamicConfigurationImpl returned: []
[3/2/17 8:55:02:999 CST] 00007fc9 AnalyticsConf 1 com.ibm.mfp.server.core.internal.configuration.analytics.AnalyticsConfigurationDeploymentHandler getAdditionalPackages:54 Exiting method: getAdditionalPackages() with value 'null'.
[3/2/17 8:55:02:999 CST] 00007fc9 RequestDetail 1 com.ibm.mfp.push.server.rest.filter.RequestDetailLogger doFilter() 
--------------------------

Request URL     :http://localhost:9081/imfpush/v1/apps/my.test.app/settings/apnsConf
Request Method  :GET
Remote address  :127.0.0.1
Request.remoteIPPort    :41309
Request.content-type    :null
Request.content-length  :0
Header map
Authorization    : Bearer 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.eyJpc3MiOiJjb20uaWJtLm1mcCIsInN1YiI6IkFkbWluX01GUF9WOF9VQVRfQ29uZmlndXJhdGlvbiIsImF1ZCI6ImNvbS5pYm0ubWZwIiwiZXhwIjoxNDg4NDY5NDQ3NjI2LCJzY29wZSI6InB1c2guYXBwcy53cml0ZSBwdXNoLmRldmljZXMud3JpdGUgcHVzaC5zdWJzY3JpcHRpb25zLndyaXRlIHB1c2gudGFncy53cml0ZSBwdXNoLmdjbUNvbmYud3JpdGUgcHVzaC5hcG5zQ29uZi53cml0ZSBwdXNoLnduc0NvbmYud3JpdGUgcHVzaC5tZXNzYWdlcy53cml0ZSBwdXNoLmFwcGxpY2F0aW9uLioifQ.V0WHTSnIBgu0hH38y10z5UNk5ey9b2xPwuGCCIcMrWiTXe80MCjP8sfPR5o153qN83oMbNSrTBNcW0uTc2ADPE7GcGQTofS_f5YsbO8wEEuzrLGhD_CnNkUhuUUPMaD-Ar5Btm1_jK2q_Ha3ZkeTFjomSIiPfMLKixD-3vK28ImCfSlaYn65QeFKtHu7gM31Fnk4UwF3TK7AlyFEspU3405WmBKjIYprgRhpyGTTDKXFETbxJAYpB1d0Hr_0xXBnN5tqMWJsv2d730Wxxh93crxEwArMuJ0V7jSlp61hJbSIs_ysnr20sFnxMYEstgzKk6l_o0kxMCYDbhkHZE67wg
Accept-Language  : en-GB,en;q=0.8,en-US;q=0.6,hi;q=0.4
Content-Length   : 0
Host     : localhost:9081
Connection   : Keep-Alive
User-Agent   : Apache-HttpClient/4.3.4 (java 1.5)
Accept-Encoding  : gzip,deflate
--------------------------

[3/2/17 8:55:02:999 CST] 00009c5e DeploymentReg 1 com.ibm.mfp.server.core.internal.deployment.registry.DeploymentRegistryImpl get:198 DeploymentRegistryImpl: get (one)- type: com.ibm.mfp.server.core.internal.configuration.analytics.AnalyticsDynamicConfigurationImpl returned: null
[3/2/17 8:55:02:999 CST] 00007fc9 DeploymentReg 1 com.ibm.mfp.server.core.internal.deployment.registry.DeploymentRegistryImpl getAll:255 DeploymentRegistryImpl: getting all- type: com.ibm.mfp.server.core.internal.configuration.analytics.AnalyticsDynamicConfigurationImpl returned: []
[3/2/17 8:55:02:999 CST] 00007fc9 DeploymentReg 1 com.ibm.mfp.server.core.internal.deployment.registry.DeploymentRegistryImpl get:198 DeploymentRegistryImpl: get (one)- type: com.ibm.mfp.server.core.internal.configuration.analytics.AnalyticsDynamicConfigurationImpl returned: null
[3/2/17 8:55:02:999 CST] 0000babb AnalyticsConf 1 com.ibm.mfp.server.core.internal.configuration.analytics.AnalyticsConfigurationDeploymentHandler getAdditionalPackages:51 Entering method: getAdditionalPackages().
[3/2/17 8:55:03:000 CST] 00007fc9 AnalyticsConf 1 com.ibm.mfp.server.core.internal.configuration.analytics.AnalyticsConfigurationDeploymentHandler getAdditionalPackages:51 Entering method: getAdditionalPackages().
[3/2/17 8:55:03:000 CST] 00007fc9 AnalyticsConf 1 com.ibm.mfp.server.core.internal.configuration.analytics.AnalyticsConfigurationDeploymentHandler getAdditionalPackages:54 Exiting method: getAdditionalPackages() with value 'null'.
[3/2/17 8:55:03:000 CST] 00007fc9 SecurityFilte > com.ibm.mfp.push.server.rest.SecurityFilter doFilter() ENTRY
[3/2/17 8:55:03:000 CST] 0000babb AnalyticsConf 1 com.ibm.mfp.server.core.internal.configuration.analytics.AnalyticsConfigurationDeploymentHandler getAdditionalPackages:54 Exiting method: getAdditionalPackages() with value 'null'.
[3/2/17 8:55:03:000 CST] 0000babb JNDIUtils     1   JNDI Access via applicationScopeLookup in /mfpadmin to mfp.admin.push.url => http://localhost:9081/imfpush
[3/2/17 8:55:03:000 CST] 00007fc9 DeploymentReg 1 com.ibm.mfp.server.core.internal.deployment.registry.DeploymentRegistryImpl getAll:255 DeploymentRegistryImpl: getting all- type: com.ibm.mfp.server.core.internal.configuration.analytics.AnalyticsDynamicConfigurationImpl returned: []
[3/2/17 8:55:03:000 CST] 00007fc9 DeploymentReg 1 com.ibm.mfp.server.core.internal.deployment.registry.DeploymentRegistryImpl get:198 DeploymentRegistryImpl: get (one)- type: com.ibm.mfp.server.core.internal.configuration.analytics.AnalyticsDynamicConfigurationImpl returned: null
[3/2/17 8:55:03:000 CST] 0000babb DeploymentReg 1 com.ibm.mfp.server.core.internal.deployment.registry.DeploymentRegistryImpl getAll:255 DeploymentRegistryImpl: getting all- type: com.ibm.mfp.server.core.internal.configuration.analytics.AnalyticsDynamicConfigurationImpl returned: []
[3/2/17 8:55:03:000 CST] 00007fc9 AnalyticsConf 1 com.ibm.mfp.server.core.internal.configuration.analytics.AnalyticsConfigurationDeploymentHandler getAdditionalPackages:51 Entering method: getAdditionalPackages().
[3/2/17 8:55:03:000 CST] 00007fc9 AnalyticsConf 1 com.ibm.mfp.server.core.internal.configuration.analytics.AnalyticsConfigurationDeploymentHandler getAdditionalPackages:54 Exiting method: getAdditionalPackages() with value 'null'.
[3/2/17 8:55:03:000 CST] 0000babb DeploymentReg 1 com.ibm.mfp.server.core.internal.deployment.registry.DeploymentRegistryImpl get:198 DeploymentRegistryImpl: get (one)- type: com.ibm.mfp.server.core.internal.configuration.analytics.AnalyticsDynamicConfigurationImpl returned: null
[3/2/17 8:55:03:000 CST] 00007fc9 SecurityFilte 1 com.ibm.mfp.push.server.rest.SecurityFilter doFilter() Security check passed
[3/2/17 8:55:03:000 CST] 00007fc9 DeploymentReg 1 com.ibm.mfp.server.core.internal.deployment.registry.DeploymentRegistryImpl getAll:255 DeploymentRegistryImpl: getting all- type: com.ibm.mfp.server.core.internal.configuration.analytics.AnalyticsDynamicConfigurationImpl returned: []
[3/2/17 8:55:03:000 CST] 0000babb AnalyticsConf 1 com.ibm.mfp.server.core.internal.configuration.analytics.AnalyticsConfigurationDeploymentHandler getAdditionalPackages:51 Entering method: getAdditionalPackages().
[3/2/17 8:55:03:000 CST] 00007fc9 DeploymentReg 1 com.ibm.mfp.server.core.internal.deployment.registry.DeploymentRegistryImpl get:198 DeploymentRegistryImpl: get (one)- type: com.ibm.mfp.server.core.internal.configuration.analytics.AnalyticsDynamicConfigurationImpl returned: null
[3/2/17 8:55:03:000 CST] 00007fc9 AnalyticsConf 1 com.ibm.mfp.server.core.internal.configuration.analytics.AnalyticsConfigurationDeploymentHandler getAdditionalPackages:51 Entering method: getAdditionalPackages().
[3/2/17 8:55:03:000 CST] 0000babb AnalyticsConf 1 com.ibm.mfp.server.core.internal.configuration.analytics.AnalyticsConfigurationDeploymentHandler getAdditionalPackages:54 Exiting method: getAdditionalPackages() with value 'null'.
[3/2/17 8:55:03:000 CST] 00007fc9 AnalyticsConf 1 com.ibm.mfp.server.core.internal.configuration.analytics.AnalyticsConfigurationDeploymentHandler getAdditionalPackages:54 Exiting method: getAdditionalPackages() with value 'null'.
[3/2/17 8:55:03:000 CST] 0000babb DataStoreClou > com.ibm.worklight.admin.datastore.DataStoreCloudantUtil useCloudant ENTRY /mfpadmin
[3/2/17 8:55:03:001 CST] 0000babb DeploymentReg 1 com.ibm.mfp.server.core.internal.deployment.registry.DeploymentRegistryImpl getAll:255 DeploymentRegistryImpl: getting all- type: com.ibm.mfp.server.core.internal.configuration.analytics.AnalyticsDynamicConfigurationImpl returned: []
[3/2/17 8:55:03:001 CST] 0000babb DeploymentReg 1 com.ibm.mfp.server.core.internal.deployment.registry.DeploymentRegistryImpl get:198 DeploymentRegistryImpl: get (one)- type: com.ibm.mfp.server.core.internal.configuration.analytics.AnalyticsDynamicConfigurationImpl returned: null
[3/2/17 8:55:03:001 CST] 0000babb AnalyticsConf 1 com.ibm.mfp.server.core.internal.configuration.analytics.AnalyticsConfigurationDeploymentHandler getAdditionalPackages:51 Entering method: getAdditionalPackages().
[3/2/17 8:55:03:001 CST] 0000babb AnalyticsConf 1 com.ibm.mfp.server.core.internal.configuration.analytics.AnalyticsConfigurationDeploymentHandler getAdditionalPackages:54 Exiting method: getAdditionalPackages() with value 'null'.
[3/2/17 8:55:03:001 CST] 0000babb JNDIUtils     1   JNDI Access found in cache for context mfpadmin and key mfp.db.cloudant.username => null
[3/2/17 8:55:03:001 CST] 0000babb DeploymentReg 1 com.ibm.mfp.server.core.internal.deployment.registry.DeploymentRegistryImpl getAll:255 DeploymentRegistryImpl: getting all- type: com.ibm.mfp.server.core.internal.configuration.analytics.AnalyticsDynamicConfigurationImpl returned: []
[3/2/17 8:55:03:001 CST] 0000babb DeploymentReg 1 com.ibm.mfp.server.core.internal.deployment.registry.DeploymentRegistryImpl get:198 DeploymentRegistryImpl: get (one)- type: com.ibm.mfp.server.core.internal.configuration.analytics.AnalyticsDynamicConfigurationImpl returned: null
[3/2/17 8:55:03:002 CST] 0000babb AnalyticsConf 1 com.ibm.mfp.server.core.internal.configuration.analytics.AnalyticsConfigurationDeploymentHandler getAdditionalPackages:51 Entering method: getAdditionalPackages().
[3/2/17 8:55:03:002 CST] 0000babb AnalyticsConf 1 com.ibm.mfp.server.core.internal.configuration.analytics.AnalyticsConfigurationDeploymentHandler getAdditionalPackages:54 Exiting method: getAdditionalPackages() with value 'null'.
[3/2/17 8:55:03:002 CST] 0000babb ContextProper 2   Found property mfp.db.cloudant.username=null in JNDI cache.
[3/2/17 8:55:03:002 CST] 0000babb DeploymentReg 1 com.ibm.mfp.server.core.internal.deployment.registry.DeploymentRegistryImpl getAll:255 DeploymentRegistryImpl: getting all- type: com.ibm.mfp.server.core.internal.configuration.analytics.AnalyticsDynamicConfigurationImpl returned: []
[3/2/17 8:55:03:002 CST] 0000babb DeploymentReg 1 com.ibm.mfp.server.core.internal.deployment.registry.DeploymentRegistryImpl get:198 DeploymentRegistryImpl: get (one)- type: com.ibm.mfp.server.core.internal.configuration.analytics.AnalyticsDynamicConfigurationImpl returned: null
[3/2/17 8:55:03:002 CST] 0000babb AnalyticsConf 1 com.ibm.mfp.server.core.internal.configuration.analytics.AnalyticsConfigurationDeploymentHandler getAdditionalPackages:51 Entering method: getAdditionalPackages().
[3/2/17 8:55:03:002 CST] 0000babb AnalyticsConf 1 com.ibm.mfp.server.core.internal.configuration.analytics.AnalyticsConfigurationDeploymentHandler getAdditionalPackages:54 Exiting method: getAdditionalPackages() with value 'null'.
[3/2/17 8:55:03:002 CST] 0000babb ContextProper 1   JNDI Access via getContextProperty in /mfpadmin to mfp.db.cloudant.username => null
[3/2/17 8:55:03:002 CST] 0000babb DeploymentReg 1 com.ibm.mfp.server.core.internal.deployment.registry.DeploymentRegistryImpl getAll:255 DeploymentRegistryImpl: getting all- type: com.ibm.mfp.server.core.internal.configuration.analytics.AnalyticsDynamicConfigurationImpl returned: []
[3/2/17 8:55:03:003 CST] 0000babb DeploymentReg 1 com.ibm.mfp.server.core.internal.deployment.registry.DeploymentRegistryImpl get:198 DeploymentRegistryImpl: get (one)- type: com.ibm.mfp.server.core.internal.configuration.analytics.AnalyticsDynamicConfigurationImpl returned: null
[3/2/17 8:55:03:003 CST] 0000babb AnalyticsConf 1 com.ibm.mfp.server.core.internal.configuration.analytics.AnalyticsConfigurationDeploymentHandler getAdditionalPackages:51 Entering method: getAdditionalPackages().
[3/2/17 8:55:03:003 CST] 0000babb AnalyticsConf 1 com.ibm.mfp.server.core.internal.configuration.analytics.AnalyticsConfigurationDeploymentHandler getAdditionalPackages:54 Exiting method: getAdditionalPackages() with value 'null'.
[3/2/17 8:55:03:003 CST] 0000babb DataStoreClou < com.ibm.worklight.admin.datastore.DataStoreCloudantUtil useCloudant RETURN false
[3/2/17 8:55:03:003 CST] 0000babb DeploymentReg 1 com.ibm.mfp.server.core.internal.deployment.registry.DeploymentRegistryImpl getAll:255 DeploymentRegistryImpl: getting all- type: com.ibm.mfp.server.core.internal.configuration.analytics.AnalyticsDynamicConfigurationImpl returned: []
[3/2/17 8:55:03:003 CST] 0000babb DeploymentReg 1 com.ibm.mfp.server.core.internal.deployment.registry.DeploymentRegistryImpl get:198 DeploymentRegistryImpl: get (one)- type: com.ibm.mfp.server.core.internal.configuration.analytics.AnalyticsDynamicConfigurationImpl returned: null
[3/2/17 8:55:03:003 CST] 0000babb AnalyticsConf 1 com.ibm.mfp.server.core.internal.configuration.analytics.AnalyticsConfigurationDeploymentHandler getAdditionalPackages:51 Entering method: getAdditionalPackages().
[3/2/17 8:55:03:004 CST] 0000babb AnalyticsConf 1 com.ibm.mfp.server.core.internal.configuration.analytics.AnalyticsConfigurationDeploymentHandler getAdditionalPackages:54 Exiting method: getAdditionalPackages() with value 'null'.
[3/2/17 8:55:03:000 CST] 00009c5e AnalyticsConf 1 com.ibm.mfp.server.core.internal.configuration.analytics.AnalyticsConfigurationDeploymentHandler getAdditionalPackages:51 Entering method: getAdditionalPackages().
[3/2/17 8:55:03:004 CST] 00009c5e AnalyticsConf 1 com.ibm.mfp.server.core.internal.configuration.analytics.AnalyticsConfigurationDeploymentHandler getAdditionalPackages:54 Exiting method: getAdditionalPackages() with value 'null'.
[3/2/17 8:55:03:004 CST] 00009c5e PushServiceIm 1 com.ibm.mfp.push.server.core.PushServiceImpl getResult param name application_name value is my.test.app
[3/2/17 8:55:03:004 CST] 00009c5e DeploymentReg 1 com.ibm.mfp.server.core.internal.deployment.registry.DeploymentRegistryImpl getAll:255 DeploymentRegistryImpl: getting all- type: com.ibm.mfp.server.core.internal.configuration.analytics.AnalyticsDynamicConfigurationImpl returned: []
[3/2/17 8:55:03:004 CST] 00009c5e DeploymentReg 1 com.ibm.mfp.server.core.internal.deployment.registry.DeploymentRegistryImpl get:198 DeploymentRegistryImpl: get (one)- type: com.ibm.mfp.server.core.internal.configuration.analytics.AnalyticsDynamicConfigurationImpl returned: null
[3/2/17 8:55:03:004 CST] 00009c5e AnalyticsConf 1 com.ibm.mfp.server.core.internal.configuration.analytics.AnalyticsConfigurationDeploymentHandler getAdditionalPackages:51 Entering method: getAdditionalPackages().
[3/2/17 8:55:03:005 CST] 00009c5e AnalyticsConf 1 com.ibm.mfp.server.core.internal.configuration.analytics.AnalyticsConfigurationDeploymentHandler getAdditionalPackages:54 Exiting method: getAdditionalPackages() with value 'null'.
[3/2/17 8:55:03:005 CST] 00009c5e PushServiceIm 1 com.ibm.mfp.push.server.core.PushServiceImpl getResult Query SQL db with size 0 and offset 0
[3/2/17 8:55:03:005 CST] 00009c5e DeploymentReg 1 com.ibm.mfp.server.core.internal.deployment.registry.DeploymentRegistryImpl getAll:255 DeploymentRegistryImpl: getting all- type: com.ibm.mfp.server.core.internal.configuration.analytics.AnalyticsDynamicConfigurationImpl returned: []
[3/2/17 8:55:03:005 CST] 00009c5e DeploymentReg 1 com.ibm.mfp.server.core.internal.deployment.registry.DeploymentRegistryImpl get:198 DeploymentRegistryImpl: get (one)- type: com.ibm.mfp.server.core.internal.configuration.analytics.AnalyticsDynamicConfigurationImpl returned: null
[3/2/17 8:55:03:005 CST] 00009c5e AnalyticsConf 1 com.ibm.mfp.server.core.internal.configuration.analytics.AnalyticsConfigurationDeploymentHandler getAdditionalPackages:51 Entering method: getAdditionalPackages().
[3/2/17 8:55:03:005 CST] 00009c5e AnalyticsConf 1 com.ibm.mfp.server.core.internal.configuration.analytics.AnalyticsConfigurationDeploymentHandler getAdditionalPackages:54 Exiting method: getAdditionalPackages() with value 'null'.
[3/2/17 8:55:03:012 CST] 00009c5e PushServiceSt 1 com.ibm.mfp.push.server.core.PushServiceStoreMeter getEnvironmentById Time taken : 16 ms..
```

Comment: Hi Prerak.  Please set a trace specification for your server and post the log here.  Your trace spec should look something like this: <logging traceSpecification="com.ibm.worklight.*=all:com.worklight.*=all:com.ibm.mfp.*=all:com.ibm.push.*=all:*=info" traceFileName="trace.log" maxFileSize="200" maxFiles="10" traceFormat="BASIC"/>

Comment: @Prerak, a device entry present in Devices section does not mean there is a push registration and subscription. Can you confirm if you did a push register and subscribe? If so, check your push_devices table in your DB to verify your subscription entry. If you dont see it, then verify your device logs to see if push registration failed and for what reason

Comment: @VivinK My device exist in the Push_devices table.

Answer (score 2):

**No devices found.** It means your app is not register for push notification.

You have to be sure that your app is able to register for push notification.

> In case of Apple Push Notification Service (APNS) , **Select following option carefully in MFP Console.**

```
1. you have to choose Production or Sandbox ?
2. Add PKCS (.p12) file with correct passowrd.
```

**Sample Code:**

> initialize app for push notification

```
        MFPPush.initialize (
        function(successResponse) {
            alert("Push Notification Successfully intialized");
            MFPPush.registerNotificationsCallback(notificationReceived);
        },
        function(failureResponse) {
            alert("Failed to initialize");
        }
    );
```

> Check device is Supported for push notification

```
        MFPPush.isPushSupported (
        function(successResponse) {
            alert("Device is Push Supported");
        },
        function(failureResponse) {
            alert("Failed to get push support status");
        }
    );
```

> register app for push notification

```
        MFPPush.registerDevice( null,
        function(successResponse) {
                alert("Device Successfully registered");
        },
        function(failureResponse) {
            alert("Failed to register");
        }
    );
```

Comment: In my case Production was selected. I imported the certificate again and then select Sandbox and then tried to send the Push message, it then displayed the success message. However in the trace log it is displaying the SSL Exception. See my updated question

Comment: @prerak As you told **displayed the success message**, but you are getting javax.net.ssl.SSLException: Received fatal alert: internal_error. 

This is related to security and  might be because of Java Version what you are using..
When it comes to security, ALWAYS use the latest updated version.

[Check here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33595021/getting-javax-net-ssl-sslexception-received-fatal-alert-protocol-version-while/35698258#35698258)

Comment: But for which certificate it is failing? I am using Java Version 7.0_71. I checked in the documentation it does not say about running it on Java 8. https://mobilefirstplatform.ibmcloud.com/tutorials/en/foundation/8.0/installation-configuration/production/

Comment: **javax.net.ssl.SSLException: Received fatal alert: internal_error** This issue is not directly related to MFP.

The load balancer network hardware did not support TLS 1.1 nor 1.2. Java made TLS 1.2 the default SSL protocol starting with Java 8, it was TLSv1 in Java 7.

Please check after updating to **java 8** and Also check if **.p12 certificate** is out of date.

Comment: @PrerakTiwari, you cannot use sandbox certificate and talk to production APN and vice versa.This is why you see SSL exceptions

Comment: @VivinK..Ok...so I generated the Production certificate and distributed my app through TestFlight to my internal Testers. This SSL error went away once I uploaded the Prod Certtificate into the MFP Server, and on the server screen I am getting the success message saying : 'The notification message was accepted for delivery.' But, I am not getting any message on the device. Check the updated logs in the question.