# Mobilefirst 8.0 cordova push notification device register failed

Tags: android, cordova, ibm-mobilefirst

I took the sample Cordova project and added platform for Android environment then I created FCM project through Google console and then I got the sender id and server key.  I added the MobileFirst server console credentials. Once I did the above steps I added the scope variable in the MobileFirst console "push.mobileclient". Finally I try to run my project using Android studio on an Android emulator.

The testing of the push notification failed while I clicked register device. Below are the error logs:

**Failed to register** `device:"com.ibm.mobilefirstplatform.clientsdk.android.push.api.MFPPushException: Response: Status=400, Text: {\"errorCode\":\"invalid_client\",\"errorMsg\":\"Incorrect JWT format\"}, Error Message: Incorrect JWT format"`

Kindly help me to resolve the issue.

Comment: You haven't provide the exact build level you are on. Please do.Also, does uninstalling and re-installing help resolve the issue?

Comment: build level means ? and i uninstall and re install apps in my native emulator.  i didn't try to install device.

Comment: Which ifix version of MFP are you on? Uninstall the application from the device and reinstall it again and check if it works fine.

Comment: i did not install ifix as of now. i just started MFP and setup local environment. Ok i will try my device then let you know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add these plugin in cordova project

```
cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-mfp
cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-mfp-push
```

Try to create fresh project in [Firebase Console](https://console.firebase.google.com) and add **Server key** & **Sender ID** in Mobilefirst console carefully.

**Run in real device. Also use same network(wifi) in both Mobile and computer.**

You can try without scope variable "push.mobileclient" in the MobileFirst console  and try sample code:

> sample code

```
    function wlCommonInit(){

   //initialize app for push notification
        MFPPush.initialize (
            function(successResponse) {
                alert("Push Notification Successfully intialized");
                MFPPush.registerNotificationsCallback(notificationReceived);
            },
            function(failureResponse) {
                alert("Failed to initialize");
            }
        );

        //Check device is Supported for push notification
        MFPPush.isPushSupported (
            function(successResponse) {
                alert("Device is Push Supported");
            },
            function(failureResponse) {
                alert("Failed to get push support status");
            }
        );

        //register app for push notification
        MFPPush.registerDevice( null,
            function(successResponse) {
                    alert("Device Successfully registered");
            },
            function(failureResponse) {
                alert("Failed to register");
            }
        );

        var notificationReceived = function(message) {
            alert(JSON.stringify(message));
        };
}
```

**Check here**: [Not able to send push notification to iOS devices through MFP Server V8 Console](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42514590/not-able-to-send-push-notification-to-ios-devices-through-mfp-server-v8-console/42528228#42528228)

Comment: **hi, i just now tried in real device which is you mentioned above that senario not working. i removed push.mobileclient as wel. still i got device register failed.**

Comment: check updated answer, and lets update  if you getting any error.

Comment: now device register problem resolved. but i could not receive push notification form operation console. i got error for ** Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: MSAN018E: The supplied value was invalid: fe80:0:0:0:ba5a:d284:a17:7de3%utun0 for serverIpAddress.** bcos i tested in android emulator

Comment: Why you are not testing in **real device **? Check Answer again and Also check Sender id and server key carefully. In Emulator you need latest google play service.

Comment: yes now its working in real device. at the moment we don't have device.thanks lot your support.

Comment: hi how to send push notification using REST API in mfp 8.0 cordova apps?

Comment: sample cordova apps working fine but i could not able to see the login page i mean user based notification i have to send