# Register device for push notification in mobilefirst 8.0 server

Tags: push-notification, ibm-mobilefirst, mobilefirst-adapters, mobilefirst-server

In MobileFirst 8.0, I developed an app registered with MobileFirst 8.0 server and install app on my device(Android). I developed and deployed an adapter on MobileFirst 8.0 Server. Everything is working fine.

But when I see 'Devices' section on server console it shows "No devices are registered in this runtime." Please any help.

Comment: Did you launch the application and did it connect to the server successfully?

Comment: Yes, application installed on device successfully contacting with the adapter deployed on server. Is their any specific steps to follow?

Comment: Not really. What does the server logs show? And how does the screenshot if the Devices tab appear?

Comment: Is it really Devices console presence you are looking for? Or registering for push notification?

Comment: As you mentioned "Everything is working fine."... are you receiving push notification ??

Comment: when i try to push notifications, i get **no device registered** error

Comment: check this answer . https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42621332/mobilefirst-8-0-cordova-push-notification-device-register-failed/42626722#42626722